# printing a wpf usercontrol on custom paper size

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

i have a wpf usercontrol with bellow properties:

1. Width=170mm(642px)
2. Height=85mm(321px)

i want to print that on a paper with above size(Width=170mm and Height=85mm)

my problem is:when i print it,some items print out of the paper,i think the paper size if Letter by default,if it is correct,how can i change it to above Width and Height?

my code is bellow:

```
        var p = new myUserControl();
        var pDoc = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

        if (pDoc.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            pDoc.PrintVisual(p, "MyPrint");
        }
```

maybe something like this needs(this is a settings for **System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog** but i use **System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog** that it has no **PrinterSettings** property):

```
    var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    var labelPaperSize = new PaperSize { RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A6, Height = 148, Width = 105 };
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = labelPaperSize;
    var labelPaperSource = new PaperSource { RawKind = (int)PaperSourceKind.Manual };
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = labelPaperSource;
    if (printerSettings.CanDuplex)
    {
        printerSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Default;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF 1 unit = 1/96 of inch, so you can calculate your size in inches using this formula

you can set printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize to the size of the Paper and then transform your window to print in that area as below:

```
private void _print()
 {
      PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

       PrintTicket pt = printDlg.PrintTicket;
       Double printableWidth = pt.PageMediaSize.Width.Value;
       Double printableHeight = pt.PageMediaSize.Height.Value;

       Double xScale = (printableWidth - xMargin * 2) / printableWidth;
       Double yScale = (printableHeight - yMargin * 2) / printableHeight;


        this.Transform = new MatrixTransform(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, xMargin, yMargin);


    //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
     printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Print Page");
}
```

Comment: how can i set printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize to the size of the Paper ?
why i must transform my usercontrol to print in that area ?

Comment: Yes, transform your usercontrol to print in that area.

Comment: my wpf usercontrol's width=642 Height=321,if p is an instance of my usercontrol ,i set ther papersize with printDlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(p.Width / 96, p.Height / 96); ok?

Comment: Incomplete solution and explanation